# reference data from entire form instead of single element

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following html on my page.

```
<form id="job" method="POST" action="#">
    <table style="text-align: left; width: 1024px; height: 371px;"
               border="1" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2">
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td style="vertical-align: top;">
            <span style="font-weight: bold;">Required:</span>
            <br>
            Enter your account number:
            <input name="account" id="job_data" type="text">
            <br>
            Pull from Core?
            <input id="pull" name="pull" checked="checked" type="checkbox">
            <br>
            Force update if data exists in coregrapher cache?
            <input id="force" name="force" type="checkbox">
            <br>
            <br>
        </td>
        <td style="vertical-align: top;"><br>
            v2.0
        </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
    <input type="submit" value="Send">
</form>
```

And on click of the submit button I want to send the data through a websocket.

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('form#job').submit(function(event) {
            var nameValue = document.getElementById("job").value;
            socket.emit('job_submit', {data: $('#job').val()});
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

I can get the value for job_data by using `socket.emit('job_submit', {data: $('#job_data').val()});`, however if I try that with #job, I get {'data':''} no matter what is in any fields.

I want to get in this case, job_data, pull, and force id's submitted.

Comment: Why not manually compose the three `val()`s into a single object? A `<form>` doesn't have a `.value`, so what exactly is jQuery supposed to do there?

Comment: @ChrisG Why do that when `.formData` and `.serialize()` exist?

Comment: @ScottMarcus Add "if you don't know how to grab an entire form's data" to the start of my comment. I basically meant "why post here, if you have all the tools to solve your issue, even though there are better options"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the **[`formData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData)** object so you can get all the name/value pairs in a collection.

Here's an example:

```js
document.querySelector("input[type='button']").addEventListener("click", function(){

  // Create a test FormData object
  var formData = new FormData(document.querySelector("form"));
  
  // You can even add to the object outside of the form
  formData.append('key1', 'value1');
  formData.append('key2', 'value2');

  // Iterate the key/value pairs
  for(var pair of formData.entries()) {
    console.log(pair[0]+ ', '+ pair[1]); 
  }
});
```

```html
<form action="#" method="get">
  <input name="firstName">
  <select name="favoriteColor">
    <option>red</option>
    <option>white</option>
    <option>blue</option>    
  </select>
  <input type="checkbox" name="agree" value="agree">I Agree
</form>

<input type="button" value="Get formData">
```

Or, with JQuery, you can use the **[`.serialize()`](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/)** method to create a querystring of the name/value pairs:

```js
$("input[type='button']").on("click", function(){

  // Create a test FormData object
  var formData = $("form").serialize();
  
  console.log(formData); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="#" method="get">
  <input name="firstName">
  <select name="favoriteColor">
    <option>red</option>
    <option>white</option>
    <option>blue</option>    
  </select>
  <input type="checkbox" name="agree" value="agree">I Agree
</form>

<input type="button" value="Get formData">
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Jquery form .serialize() command from the click event.  Snippet below.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="job" method="POST" action="#">
    <table style="text-align: left; width: 1024px; height: 371px;"
               border="1" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2">
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td style="vertical-align: top;">
            <span style="font-weight: bold;">Required:</span>
            <br>
            Enter your account number:
            <input name="account" id="job_data" type="text">
            <br>
            Pull from Core?
            <input id="pull" name="pull" checked="checked" type="checkbox">
            <br>
            Force update if data exists in coregrapher cache?
            <input id="force" name="force" type="checkbox">
            <br>
            <br>
        </td>
        <td style="vertical-align: top;"><br>
            v2.0
        </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
    <input type="submit" value="Send">
</form>
And on click of the submit button I want to send the data through a websocket.

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('form#job').submit(function(event) {
            var nameValue = JSON.stringify($(event.target).serialize());
            //socket.emit('job_submit', {data: $('#job').val()});
            alert(nameValue);
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```